# Even if my Azure widevine license has expired, I can still play content

Tags: exoplayer, azure-media-services, drm, widevine, shaka

Azure Media Service is used to deliver widevine license, I used shaka-packager with key-id and key-value get from license to package and encrypt video, and output two types of files, MPD, and MP4 encrypted video.

When I test the encrypted content with the Dash test player, everything works fine and without a license, I can not play video.

Then when I override policies and
set license_duration_seconds = 1800

The player stops after 30 minutes and displays "DRM: KeyStatusChange error! -- License has expired"

However, when I click on Load again or refresh the page and use the same license and MPD URL, the same content plays again!

I'm not sure if I missed something when I package the video with shaka-player.

Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you "click on Load again or refresh the page", are you sure the player did not get a new Widevine license (hence another 30 min of playback window)?

Is this a browser app or native/non-browser app? The reason I ask this: not every Widevine environment supports persistent license. Android native app and Android Chrome support it. If you expect license re-use, persistent license is required and needs to be supported.

Comment: Hi William
Regarding the player getting a new widevine License is this the default behavior if I do not specify that the license is renewable? How can I be sure if there are new license from Azure Portal?

I use this policies in license:
can_play = true, can_persist = false, can_renew = false, license_duration_seconds = 1800

The player I use is the browser app Dash javaScript Player and sometimes I use exoplayer

Comment: Another question because I think I have a misunderstanding, I used to think that the persistent license was only I need it when I want to play a video in offline mode, why is it important in this scenario?

Comment: Your settings indicate the Widevine license is not persisted, hence refresh will request a new license, consistent with your observation.

Comment: You can use Fiddler to see license request. Persistent license is not only for offline mode. In online mode, if persistent license is supported by a DRM platform and enabled, license can be persisted and reused. This can reduce license request number, reducing cloud cost, especially if you combine the design technique that a group of contents sharing the same content key (hence key ID). For more details, see the reference design section of this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/architecture-design-multi-drm-system.

Comment: I understand now, thanks William I appreciate your kind help.